# update case status for multiple order updates

Tags: apex, trigger

Need help to modify a trigger to update the Case status if Order status changes.
below trigger is working but seems if for only one Order status change. need to modify the trigger if ALL Order records related to Case have status changed, then Case status updated .
thanks

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    public String currentCaseId {get;set;}
    List<Order> OrderList = new List<Order>();
    for (Order Ord:trigger.new) {
        OrderList.add(Ord);
        currentCaseId=Ord.Case__c;
    }

    List<Case> CaseList = new List<Case>([select Id,Status from Case where Id = :currentCaseId]);

    String caseApproved = 'Approved';
    String caseCompleted = 'Completed';
    String caseInvalid = 'Invalid';
    String caseRejected = 'Rejected';
    String caseNew = 'New';
    String caseIncomplete = 'Incomplete';
    String caseInProgress = 'In-Progress';

    for (Order currentOrd: OrderList) {
        for (Case ordCase: CaseList) {
            if(currentOrd.Status == caseApproved) {
                ordCase.Status = caseCompleted;
            }
            if(currentOrd.Status == caseInvalid) {
                ordCase.Status = caseRejected;
            }
            if(currentOrd.Status == caseNew || currentOrd.Status == caseIncomplete) {
                ordCase.Status = caseInProgress;
            }
        }
    }
    update CaseList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bulkify your code like:

Update: Use `Set<sObject>` instead of `List<sObject>`. If many orders have same associated case, the last order status will be update to the case.

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Order Ord :Trigger.new) {
        caseIds.add(Ord.Case__c); //Get all orders associated case ids
    }

    Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds]);//Get corresponding case details
    Map<Id, Case> mapCase = new Map<Id, Case>();

    String caseApproved = 'Approved';
    String caseCompleted = 'Completed';
    String caseInvalid = 'Invalid';
    String caseRejected = 'Rejected';
    String caseNew = 'New';
    String caseIncomplete = 'Incomplete';
    String caseInProgress = 'In-Progress';

    //For insert and update trigger
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for (Order currentOrd : Trigger.new) {
            Case ordCase = caseMap.get(currentOrd.Case__c)

            if(currentOrd.Status == caseApproved) {
                ordCase.Status = caseCompleted;
            }
            if(currentOrd.Status == caseInvalid) {
                ordCase.Status = caseRejected;
            }
            if(currentOrd.Status == caseNew || currentOrd.Status == caseIncomplete) {
                ordCase.Status = caseInProgress;
            }
            mapCase.put(ordCase.Id, ordCase);
        }
    }
    else if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for (Order currentOrd : Trigger.new) {
            //----your logic----
        }
    }
    update mapCase.values();
}
```

Note: Always have a handler class for trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Reshma for your quick response. will try this out too. thank u.

Comment: got this error " variable does not exist: Ord " in Line 22. thanks for assistance.

Comment: Updated my code. Please try and let me know. @vlink

Comment: thanks Reshma, I got this error now "duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>".  in Line 0. can't trace that error msg.

Comment: yes I tried it.

Comment: @vlink please try the updated code and check

Comment: got this error this time "DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Set<Case>" in Line 41.... (second from last Line - update CaseList . I changed it to "update CaseSet instead.)

Comment: thanks Sir, same error msg "duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>".

Comment: Hi Reshma, good day. I tried your code earlier today and it's also worked. but I just noticed that the trigger works for every changes in Order. just note that in every Cases, there are lots of Orders....if only one order changes for that Case, the Case should not change the status. but if all the orders in that particular Case have the same status (says all are change status to "Approved") its only then the Case status for that orders will change to Completed. thanks in advance.

Comment: @vlink Gald to help you. If you have different question please [ask a new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and add a link to relate this question. Thanks !

Comment: thanks. I posted another question related to that.